# Registration Form using Password with Validation

Tags: c#, validation, passwords

I have two text boxes to enter password and re-type password which lead to my database, was wondering what is the process is making it mandatory for the two passwords to match?

Answer (score 0):

Is it asp.net or windows application? It seems you are using windows (since there is no tag for asp.net). If that is the case then you simply check the text of the textboxes to be same and if they are then add it to the database else you show a red astrik in a label next to the `confirm password textbox` and show your message in a tooltip of the label.

If this is not what you are looking for then please comment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is windows, doing this through visual studios 2012

Comment: Okay so my solution should hold good. Did you tried it out? If you are facing any issues then please comment

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this...

since it is a windows application..

```
if(txtPassword.text == txtConfirmPassword.text)
{
do whatever.....
}
else
{
give an error message...
}
```